# Two Kafa consumer with one producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I have two kafka consumers defined in two micro services  from one producer with different group id defined.One of the micro service is not consuming the message from the producer

---

```
@Component
@ConditionalOnProperty(value = "XXX", havingValue = "true")
public class EventListener {


  @KafkaListener(id = "XX", topics = "#{'${topic'}")
  public void consumeMessageEvent(Event messageEvent, ConsumerRecord<String, ?> record) {

  }

  }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about *what* code you're running? http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise

Comment: Edit your question to include the code so that it's properly formatted.

Comment: you did not give consumer group name in @KafkaListener(id = "XX", topics = "#{'${topic'}") annotation. where did you specify different group id's ?